# Data not passing in ionic 2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2

I am working on ionic 2 project. In this I want the data to be passed on the basis of date from **Firebase**.

I am getting the data in provider from **Firebase** but I am unable to send it to the other pages

My function in provider is as follows

```
getTodaysQuestions() {
  var today = new Date();

  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var day = "";
  var month = "";
  if (dd < 10) {
    day = "0" + dd;
  } else {
    day = "" + dd;
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    month = "0" + mm;
  } else {
    month = "" + mm;
  }
  var d = day + month + yyyy;
  console.log(d);

  var fbstring = "/Daily/" + d;
  console.log(fbstring);
  var qstring = "/Questions/q/";

  this.afd.list(fbstring).valueChanges().subscribe(
    m => {
      //for each m, get actual questions from fb
      console.log(m);
      for (var x in m) {
        console.log(x);
        var str = qstring + m[x];
        console.log(str);

        console.log(this.questions);
        this.afd.list(str).valueChanges().subscribe(
          n => {
            console.log(n);
            this.questions = n;
            //this.questions.push(n);
            console.log(this.questions);
            return this.questions;


          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

when I am calling this function in my home.ts I am getting undefined value.

```
mydata: any;


this.mydata = this.data.getTodaysQuestions();
console.log(this.mydata);
```

Comment: getTodaysQuestions() function are in home.ts and console.log(this.mydata); are showing undefined........

Comment: getTodaysQuestions() is in proviser firebase.ts and I called it in home.ts

Comment: I dont know anything about typescript but firebase works asynchronous so you cant just return the values you are getting, instead you have to return a promise that will resolve when you get the data back from firebase.

Comment: but how to do it

Comment: i think its working asynchronously

Comment: use `.map` instead `.valueChanges().subscribe` and follow SrAxi's answer.

Comment: @Hareesh how to use plz can you give solution

Comment: Its not working can you give me solution plz

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your function

```
return this.afd.list(fbstring).valueChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(m => { 
        //for each m, get actual questions from fb
        console.log(m);
        for (var x in m) {
            console.log(x);
            var str = qstring + m[x];
            console.log(str);

            return this.afd.list(str).valueChanges();

        }
    });
});
```

and in `home.ts`

```
mydata: Observable<any>;

this.mydata = this.data.getTodaysQuestions();
this.mydata.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: its not giving me actual data its giving me other metadata

Comment: are you getting correct value here `console.log(str);`

Comment: its not giving any value in console i think it is not calling it

Comment: can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), that will be easy to check.

Comment: I have to put my project on it?

Comment: you have to connect with the firebase credentials, then put only relevant component not all project

Comment: or create a test database in firebase and mock your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166450/discussion-between-faisal-amdani-and-hareesh).

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, you have 2 subscriptions to Observables, therefore you should handle that async data stream.

```
getTodaysQuestions(): Observable<any> {
  var today = new Date();

  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var day = "";
  var month = "";
  if (dd < 10) {
    day = "0" + dd;
  } else {
    day = "" + dd;
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    month = "0" + mm;
  } else {
    month = "" + mm;
  }
  var d = day + month + yyyy;
  console.log(d);

  var fbstring = "/Daily/" + d;
  console.log(fbstring);
  var qstring = "/Questions/q/";

  return this.afd.list(fbstring).valueChanges().subscribe(
    m => {
      //for each m, get actual questions from fb
      console.log(m);
      for (var x in m) {
        console.log(x);
        var str = qstring + m[x];
        console.log(str);

        console.log(this.questions);
       return this.afd.list(str).valueChanges().subscribe(
          n => {
            console.log(n);
            this.questions = n;
            //this.questions.push(n);
            console.log(this.questions);
            return this.questions;


          }
        );
      }
    });
}
```

Now `getTodaysQuestions()` returns an Observable. Now you should be able to subscribe to it:

```
this.data.getTodaysQuestions().subscribe((data: any) => {
   this.mydata = data;
   console.log(this.mydata);
});
```

Comment: @SrAxi Don't forget that the `getTodaysQuestions()` function also has to be changed to provide the promise you want to use await on.

Comment: how to do that plz can u give solution

Comment: @AndréKool Yep, I changed it into Observable, that's what he's handling right now.